# Organizing CSS files with many breakpoints and many templates

Tags: css, html, wordpress, sass, html5boilerplate

I'm beginning CSS, HTML, and Sass, and while I understand the basics, I'd like to start getting into best practices.  I'm building a responsive portfolio website (using Bones HTML5 Boilerplate & Wordpress), that will have 4-5 breakpoints, as well as ~5 different static site templates.

My breakpoints are imported based on media queries from code in multiple .scss files, like so:

```
_base_res.scss
_481_and_up.scss
_768_and_up.scss
_1030_and_up.scss
```

Right now, I also have a number of static pages that have media queries within them:

```
_home.scss
_about.scss
_contact.scss
_work.scss
```

Is it redundant to have the static page css files that contain media queries as well as breakpoint css files?  Should I just have classes .home, .about, .contact, .work within the breakpoint scss files?

Sorry if my question is not clear.. if not, please let me know how I might be able to clarify.

Thanks

Comment: I'd say it is your decision. I am one of those people that will write media queries for each element and choose the width for the queries based on my content, instead of for example mobile, tablet and desktop looks, which would make media querie files redundant, I also find it a  lot more accessible to group every style within my element, which is what I think also what the sass people had in mind, why else would you be able to group the media queries within the element.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading into and about https://smacss.com/ this will teach you how to create good css architecture. Also I would recommend writing a mixin that will allow you to pass media query variables. Once that is done write out your media queries where you need them not on specific stylesheets.